# how to use ajax in JQuery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have that works  fine without Script manager. but if I add script manager that getting an error: sys undefined.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Block-ui-pageload.aspx.cs" Inherits="Block_ui_pageload" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="divConfirmBox1">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvCategories" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCategoryName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="showDeleteConfirmation('<%# Eval(" CategoryId")=CategoryId") %=% />')" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            &nbsp;
            <div id="divConfirmBox" style="display:none">
                Are you sure you want to delete this record?
                <input type="button" value="No" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#divConfirmBox1').block({ message: $('#divConfirmBox') });
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#divConfirmBox').click(function (event) {
            $('#divConfirmBox1').unblock();
        });
    });
</script>
```

initially during the page load . I am   blocking the screen(PAge). once the user  clicks   the button the page is unblocked.
 is there  anything wrong in the Syntax  whiling working with Ajax script manager

Comment: You don't have any Ajax code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web.config  we   need  to   add the follwing code within  tag.

then  the  problem was  solved
 every thing was  working fine

Answer (score 1):

You should move the jQuery code into $(document).ready. I suspect you're preventing certain scripts from loading appropriately by running the code inline rather than in .ready. I'm running the same version of jQuery (but not UI block) with ScriptManager in 3.5 right now, no prob.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is not a thing - its a bunch of technologies put together to achieve asynchronous communication. Yes, you have some JavaScript coding in there, but none of them actually do anything 'ajaxian' - a good example of something really AJAX-style would be an validation of a (registration) form or something like that. You'd set some oberservers for some fields and validate them whilst the user is still making inputs on other fields...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [noConflict](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict). It's been a while since I've used asp.net ajax but if I'm not mistaken, there is a `$` function defined.