# Javascript get content from json output and save to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON output script called index_list.php and the output is:

```
{"index":"1","name":"VALUE1"},
{"index":"2","name":"VALUE2"},
{"index":"3","name":"VALUE3"},
```

The select:

```
<select name="selectId" id="selectId"></select>
```

The javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-graphAdd", function () {
    var host_ip = $(this).data('ip');
    $(".modal-body #host_ip").val( host_ip );

    html = "";
    obj = {
        "1" : "VALUE1",
        "2" : "VALUE2",
        "3" : "VALUE3"
    }
    for(var key in obj) {
        html += "<option value=" + key  + ">" +obj[key] + "</option>"
    }
    document.getElementById("selectId").innerHTML = html;
```

This works great, but need the variable "obj" to get the values from index_list.php?ip="+host_ip

I get the code from [How to create HTML select option from JSON hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071525/how-to-create-html-select-option-from-json-hash)

Thanks.

Comment: Read up on ajax. Oh, and, by the way, what you showed is not a valid json.

Comment: there are probably thousands of threads on here about ajax..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use ajax in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353379/how-to-use-ajax-in-jquery)

Comment: Also note that what you produce in your PHP is not valid JSON: you're allowed only one top-level object or array. Paste it into http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user clicks, you need to make an ajax call:

```
 $.post( "index_list.php?ip="+theip, function(resp){
        obj = JSON.parse(resp);
        doExactlyWhatYouDidButWithThisObject(obj);          
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    });
```

I am assuming you are using jquery, but you could do the same with an xmlhttprequest if you don't want jquery

Answer (score 1):

> var url = "index_list.php?ip="+host_ip
>
> $.get( url, function( data ) {   obj = data; });